# Can I do it by using chinese remainder theorem?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Use the following solution

$X≡ 31\mod 5^3$

$X≡ 93\mod 5^3$

$X≡ 4\mod 7$

$X≡ 2\mod 7$

to generate all solutions
to $x^2+x+8≡ 0\mod 875$

Can I do it by using Chinese remainder theorem like this $X≡ 93\mod 5^3$ and

$X≡ 4\mod 7$ together and $X≡ 2\mod 7$ and $X≡ 31\mod 5^3)$ together

and after that the result of these together?

Comment: Yes, just take each possibility in turn from the two modulus values and resolve through CRT. I worked through a similar exercise [at this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483312/find-all-four-solutions-x2-equiv-133-pmod-143/2483447#2483447)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two options under each modulus value

$\begin{align}
X &\equiv \{2,4\} \bmod 7 \\
X &\equiv \{31,93\} \bmod 125 \\
\end{align}$

and you can just take each combination of values from these two modulus values to get the four answers to $\bmod 875$

As a preliminary step find $125^{-1}\equiv 6^{-1} \equiv 6 \bmod 7$

Then for example:

$\left .
\begin{align}
X & \equiv 2 \bmod 7 \\
X & \equiv 31 \bmod 125 \end{align}
\right\}\space
31+125k \equiv 2 \Rightarrow 3+6k \equiv 2 \Rightarrow k\equiv 6^{-1} (-1) \equiv 1 \bmod 7 \\\implies X\equiv 31+125\cdot 1 \equiv 156 \bmod 875$

And similarly for the pairings $(2,93)$, $(4,31)$, $(4,93)$.